# A curved arrow disappears when its end position is specified in xymatrix

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, xymatrix

I want to draw a curved arrow with specifing its end position in xymatrix.
I tried the following code.

```
\xymatrix{
      A \ar@{=>}@/^/[r] & B \\
      C \ar@{=>}[r]+<-5pt,3pt> & D \\
      E \ar@{=>}@/^/[r]+<-5pt,3pt> & F \\
}
```

Then I get the following image.

[image: the resulting image]

While the A-to-B and C-to-D arrows appear correctly, the E-to-F arrow disappears except for the arrow head. That is, I was able to draw a curved arrow without specifying its end position and a straight arrow with specifying its end position. I received the following warning for my code:

```
Xy-pic Warning: start of break not found: bSTART=1.0, bEND=1
```

How should I write a curved arrow with specifying its end position?

Comment: `Xy-pic Warning: start of break not found: bSTART=1.0, bEND=1`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added the information to my question.